# How to know which editor published a post programmatically?

Tags: wp-query, user-roles, editor

I have authors posting posts with a custom post type and have users with Editor roles publishing them. How can I get the editors who published them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, WordPress only stores original authors of the posts. If you want to also save the publisher's ID, you need to do a bit of custom coding, or use some 3rd party plugin.

Essentially what you need to do is to store the user ID whenever the post status is being changed to `publish`. For that you can use the `publish_{your_post_type}` action (replace {your_post_type} with your custom post type slug). If your CPT slug is `project` for example, your action should look like this:

```
function save_project_publisher_meta( $post_id ) {

    // Set current user ID as a post meta
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'publisher_id', get_current_user_id() );
}
add_action( 'publish_project', 'save_project_publisher_meta', 10 );
```

Now the publisher ID should be stored as a post meta for each post, and you can access the user data whenever you need by retrieving the publisher ID using `get_post_meta`:

```
// Get WP_User object from ID
$publisher_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'publisher_id', true );
$publisher = get_user_by( 'id', $publisher_id );

// Get whatever user data you need
$publisher_email = $publisher->user_email;
```

Note this will only affect newly published posts. Posts that were published in the past won't have publisher IDs stored, until you re-publish them.

Comment: This is outstanding! I'll test it out now.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress don't have native functionality to handle changes around post/page from users. You need to write / or use plugin to get them and control your authors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).